# Opt out of SO for Teams email without opting out of other features and announcements

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams, email

I have no use for Stack Overflow for Teams and do not want to get email announcements related to it. As far as I can tell, the only way to unsubscribe from them is to unsubscribe from "Features and Announcements." But I want to get email for new features and announcements regarding **Stack Overflow**. Just not Stack Overflow for Teams.

Please add an option to opt-out of Teams-related email without opting out of other Features and Announcements.

Comment: Can you create a filter for that in your email client? (I don't get such emails, so I don't know whether differences or similarities between the subject or from field allow for this)

Comment: @Dukeling - Probably, although it would almost certainly be imperfect. "Our Moderator Teams Need Your Help" would run afoul of one, for instance.

Comment: and likely also block anything else that just happens to mention teams... which is likely, due to it being something they want to promote.

Comment: Microsoft sending me emails every minute to repeat all the instant messages sent across the department, I already banned the word "Teams" in my professional mailbox.